# SQL: Count different steps that occur on different times in a process and group by client and date

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Problem**
For reporting purpose I am creating a view that returns aggregated data. We have multiple clients that have multiple cases in our database. A case will have different statuses, dependent on the phase of the process it is in. The timestamps of the most important transitions in the process are logged on case-level, in different columns.

**This is the result I need:**
date |
client |
count_new_case |
count_step1_case |
count_step2_case |
count_completed_case

**The data looks like this:**
case_id |
client |
timstamp_created |
timestamp_step1 |
timestamp_step2 |
timestamp_completed

Comment: Make it easy to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY client` and count only cases of a type using `CASE`. That might look similar to:

```
SELECT current_date date,
       client,
       count(CASE
               WHEN timestamp_step1 IS NULL THEN
                 1
             END) count_new_case,
       count(CASE
               WHEN timestamp_step1 IS NOT NULL
                    AND timestamp_step2 IS NULL THEN
                 1
             END) count_step1_case,
       count(CASE
               WHEN timestamp_step2 IS NOT NULL
                    AND timestamp_completed IS NULL THEN
                 1
             END) count_step2_case,
       count(CASE
               WHEN timestamp_completed IS NOT NULL THEN
                 1
             END) count_completed_case
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY client;
```

You didn't tell the exact logic when a case qualifies as new, step 1, etc. so I had to guess here. You might want to adapt that.